# Google Sheets ImportXML from Etsy- Import data from multiple pages with dynamic navigation

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape data from some Etsy shops using Google Sheets.  Specifically, I'm looking to import the product names in the seller's reviews (outlined in red in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxSQS.jpg)).  I've successfully imported these names using the following formula where the seller's Etsy URL (https://www.etsy.com/shop/PaperLarkDesigns) is located in cell B4:

```
=IMPORTXML(B4, "//div[@class='flag-body hide-xs hide-sm']")
```

But the navigation for the product reviews is dynamically generated, so the formula only imports the titles from the first page of reviews and there doesn't seem to be a URL to direct the formula to a specific page of reviews.

Is there a way to denote which page of reviews the importXML formula should pull these titles from?  Or is it not possible to pull data from a site using this type of navigation?

I'm new to the more complex formulas in Excel/ Google Sheets, so thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the use of `IMPORTXML` in this situation is **not** possible.

According to the `IMPORTXML` [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en):

> `IMPORTXML` imports data from any of various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds.

Therefore, the `=IMPORTXML()` command you are using reads the `HTML` source of the page without any JavaScript code associated with it and **without** executing it - the reason why you are not able to retrieve the wanted data from it.

#### Reference

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)